# Pandas Series unique method showing values looking the same

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas dataframe. When I run the .unique() method to one of the columns, it shows values looking the same. How can I see how these values differ? I tried to index from the unique() method but the values were just the strings as shown below. Thanks for the help.

```
df["MyColumn"].unique()
array(['yi̇', 'yd', 'yi'], dtype=object)
_______________________________________
df["MyColumn"].unique()[0]
'yi̇'
_______________________________________
df["MyColumn"].unique()[2]
'yi̇'
```

Comment: maybe you can filter the dataframe, `df[df["MyColumn"] == df["MyColumn"].unique()[2]]` and `df[df["MyColumn"] == df["MyColumn"].unique()[0]]`

Comment: It is not an alphabetic character 'i', it is a different unicode [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm)
The length of the character is 2
`[len(i) for i in ['i̇', 'd', 'i']]` returns
`[2, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check asci code what is difference, here after first `i` is special value `775` like mnetioned in comment [`Er Bharath Ram`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm):

```
u = ['yi̇', 'yd', 'yi']
print ([list(map(ord,i)) for i in u])
[[121, 105, 775], [121, 100], [121, 105]]
```

Answer (score 1):

On closer inspection you see the difference:

```
'yi̇' # the i letter has two dots
'yi' # normal i letter
```

So you seem to look at two different unicode characters, which however look very similar.